# How to prevent cleveref from using ranges

Tags: cleveref, amsthm

I'm using the cleveref package with amsthm.

`\Cref{thm:a,thm:b,thm:c,thm:d}` becomes `Theorems 1 to 4`
I want it to become `Theorems 1, 2, 3 and 4`.
How can I do this?

I want it this way because I'm also using hyperref and I would like to click-to-go to all the theorems.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\title{Testing cleveref with amsthm}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:a} The first theorem. \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:b} The second theorem. \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:c} The third theorem. \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:d} The fourth theorem. \end{theorem}

\Cref{thm:a,thm:b,thm:c,thm:d}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: From the proposed duplicate question particularly the second answer is relevant, which mentions using empty references to suppress ranges (so in your case `\Cref{thm:a,,thm:b,,thm:c,,thm:d}`).

Comment: Using either the option `sort` or `nosort` works. Using `\Cref{thm:a,,thm:b,,thm:c,,thm:d}` also works.

Comment: The difference is if you want this behavior for all references (first answer) or just for some of them (second answer).